# JNA array of structures uninitialized after being passed from Java to C

Tags: java, c, arrays, jna, structure

I've been using JNA with relative success to make native function calls from Java to a small C library that I wrote. Passing structures or pointers from one to the other works great once you've worked out the tricks of structure mapping, memory management and passing by reference.

I am now trying to pass, from Java to C, an array of structures. Here is the C code for the structure:

```
typedef struct key {
  int length;
  void *data;
} key_t;
```

I have the matching definition in Java:

```
public class Key extends Structure {

  public int length;
  public Pointer data;

  public Key() {
    this.setFieldOrder(new String[] {"length", "data"});
  }

  public void setAsLong(long value) {
    this.length = 8;
    this.data = new Memory(this.length);
    this.data.setLong(0, value);
  }

  public long longValue() {
    return this.data != null ? this.data.getLong(0) : Long.MIN_VALUE;
  }
};
```

If I understood the documentation and what I read online, I need to create my array as a contiguous memory section by doing the following on the Java side:

```
Key[] keys = new Key().toArray(2);
for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
  k.setAsLong(42+i);
}
```

So far so good. If I dump the content of each `Key` structure in Java using `Structure.toString()`, everything is in here as expected. Note that the code about setting as a long value, allocating memory for the key's content, etc, work fine when I pass a single `Key` structure from Java to C. So here I pass my array to my native function by using the pointer to the first element of the array:

```
instance.foo(keys[0].getPointer(), keys.length);
```

My C function is of course defined like this:

```
void foo(key_t *keys, size_t count) {
  ...;
}
```

The array gets there correctly: the `keys` pointer on the C side has the same address as `keys[0].getPointer()` in Java, but unfortunately the members of each structure in the array are `0/NULL`, as pointed out by GDB:

```
(gdb) print keys
$1 = (key_t *) 0x7fd7e82389e0
(gdb) print keys[0]
$2 = {length = 0, data = 0x0}
```

At this point I honestly have no clue what's going on. As I said, if I pass just one structure, it works fine, but here no way. The only difference I can see is the Java native method signature which uses `Pointer` instead of `Key[]` but when I use the array I get:

```
IllegalArgumentException: [Lfoo.bar.Key; is not a supported argument type (in method foo ...
```

Thanks

Comment: A Java array is not a C array.  And you can't "take the address" of the first element of a Java array.

Comment: Is the data behind your `data` field always 64 bits?  If not, Java `long` is not the correct type to be using.

Comment: @HotLicks: Apparenly by using new Key().toArray() you to get a natively-allocated, contiguous memory region, which means the address of the first element of the array is valid to reference the array, even from the native side.

Comment: @technomage: Not always, the data in the key is freeform (hence the `void*`). Here I just added utility methods to put a `long` in it and retrieve it easily.

Comment: I have my doubts.  When you say `keys[0]` the address of `keys` is gone -- you're getting the contents of the first element.

Comment: There should be a standard way to pass an array of object pointers.  The first object pointer begins 8-16 bytes into the array object.  Taking the address of the first element is not the way to go, since Java doesn't understand "taking the address" and can't translate it into a native method call.

Comment: In this case is the fact that it's working just a coincidence? I see your point, and I see why (at least on the Java side) the address of the first element (`keys[0]`) is not the same as the address of the array `keys` itself, but then I'm puzzled as to why (and how) it works.

Comment: @HotLicks he's not passing an array of object pointers, he's passing an array of `struct`, in which case the address of the array and the address of the first element are interchangeable.  While not strictly true on the Java side, JNA attempts to make the common usage similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass a `Pointer` value, JNA has no idea that you're actually passing a `Structure` or an array of them, and it's up to you to ensure you call `Structure.write()` before and `Structure.read()` after the native call.

If you pass either a `Structure` or `Structure[]`, then JNA will take care of the synchronization automagically.  In the case of `Structure`, JNA uses internal bookkeeping to determine whether the structure you're passing is at the head of an array of structures.

Comment: BTW, `Key[]` should work as an argument type.  If it doesn't (and there's not something else going on), then you should file an issue on the JNA project site (preferably with a reproducible test case).

Comment: Hum, ok. I'll try to make a reproducible test case then, because using `Key[]` clearly doesn't work in my case as I mentioned at the end of my question. I'll try using `.write()`, it makes a lot of sense and would explain why the contents of the structure remain `NULL`.

Comment: Using `.write()` worked, thanks. I'll try to follow up with JNA on Github to see why using `Key[]` doesn't work.